# In responsive web design, after a resize, how can one know that the layout was performed?

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I've noticed that if I attach an event listener to the window resize event, I get the resize event and the window.innerWidth is somewhat correct (with the exception of iPads/iPhones which just behave erratically), but the page layout hasn't been performed yet.

I need to wait for the layout so I could perform further work on the page, how would I know the layout has been performed without some random debouncing mechanism?

Here's a pen illustrating the problem:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Yraqpm#anon-login

HTML:

```
<div class="fullwidth">
    THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A 
    TEST THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST THIS IS A TEST
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    .fullwidth {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: red
    }
```

JS:

```
    var resizeInvoked = function() {
        alert(window.innerWidth);
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeInvoked);
```

Notice that when you maximize the window you get the alert before the responsive div is adjusted to the new layout....

Comment: Are you talking about how the visual representation of the div hasn't been re-rendered when the alert shows? That's an abstracted browser dependent optimization that you have no control over. If you programmatically check properties such as `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` on the div element in your onResize handler you'll see that it has logically adjusted to the new layout already.

Comment: yea, I'm talking about the visual representation. I understand what you mean, but for some reason on iOS devices things don't work as expected... When I get a resize and check the width or available scroll area on iOS devices the values are wrong, if I debouce it for a few hundred ms I get the correct values

Comment: just found this bug report: http://www.openradar.me/31725316 , how OK is it to curse the hell out of Apple at stackoverflow?